# How do I redirect a website to local website?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redirect

I am trying to make my browser load local website instead of visiting actual website.

I have this httpd configuration

```
<VirtualHost 140.82.113.4:80>
    ServerName www.github.com
    ServerAlias github.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/local/website
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 140.82.113.4:443>
    ServerName www.github.com
    ServerAlias github.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/local/website
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/github.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/github.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type in the browser https://github.com, it still loads the real website. I want it to load the local files at /path/to/local/website/index.html not go to the real one. What else do I need to configure?

Comment: Do you have set resolution of github to 140.82.113.4 (probably your IP)?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in browsing a website is resolving the name to an ip address. While your web server might be hosting a "mock" github site, your DNS client isn't resolving github.com or [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) to your web server ip address. For that you'd need a DNS server hosting a DNS zone for github.com, containing the relevant DNS records for github.com. Then you'd have to configure your DNS client to use your DNS server for DNS name resolution.

Comment: Can they not just put the relevant hostnames in their hosts file and point them to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Own DNS server is overkill. as already mentioned `/etc/hosts` (and proper /etc/nsswitch.conf) is just fine. :)

Comment: Of course they could use the hosts file, but there's nothing wrong with setting up their own DNS server for this, especially if they plan to use this with multiple clients and multiple websites.

Comment: How do I set it up in host file. Do I state 140.82.113.4 localhost